# Is it a must to download and install all packages when install Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude D620 laptop, using a USB stick. What I can see during the installation is that it is downloading packages from the internet, including language packs. I go ahead and click that 'skip' button then restart. But there comes a system error after I log in, plus I can't open 'additional drivers'.
The error's not gone until an 'sudo apt-get update'+'sudo apt-get upgrade'+'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade', and after that I can open 'additional drivers' to install nVidia drivers.
So my question is, is it a must to download and install all packages during installation? If it is, why does Ubuntu provide a button 'skip'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if "Downloading" in this part of the dialog isn't rather refering to "downloading" from the CD. Normally you would have selected "Download Updates" on the first page of the dialog.

Only downloading the updates can be a lot of data however. If you are using third party components like proprietary nvidia drivers, it could be that those have to be downloaded from the internet.

If you leave all option boxes on the first dialog page unchecked, there should be no downloads from the internet at all. If you read the phrase "downloading" then, you can be sure it's refering to copying from the CD.

If you don't download and install updates during the installation, then updating should be the first thing to do after you boot your new Ubuntu.

Comment: No, it is not downloading from the CD, coz' I can see the downloading address `http://cnarchive.ubuntu.com` (something like that) and speed (35KB/s, which is not so ideal). And yes, it seems that I should update my fresh installed Ubuntu to latest first before installing nVidia drivers. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not a must. It is optional. There is some info here about installing ubuntu in a virtual enviorenment.
http://cybrwrld.blogspot.com/2012/10/feel-ubuntu-ubuntu-on-virtual-box.html